# How can I clone a whole project in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to run some tests in my project but I do not want to affect the 
original code, and I wanto to clone the project so I can run tests there

Does anyone know how to clone a project on IntelliJ Idea 11?

Comment: Just make a copy of the project directory. Unless you want to commit from the "clone" and are using an annoying VCS that keeps a global registry of checkout locations (like TFS) this should work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using your operating system File Explorer tool, just copy and paste the entire project directory somewhere new. All of the configuration should use relative paths by default.

If your IDEA project is .ipr based, then delete the new .iws file before opening the project. 
If your IDEA project is .idea directory based, then delete the workspace.xml file before opening the project.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should also delete any version control directories like `.git` so you can commit your work to a new repository, if you want.

Comment: You might want to rename the new project's package if it's not the same as the old project's.

Comment: IntelliJ latest versions allows project duplication within the IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61665059/9567003

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy and rename the project too, like I wanted to clone a project in order to use it with a newer version of IntelliJ.

1. Copy the whole directory to a new location, for example on Linux:

   `cp -r myproject new/location/`
2. To rename the project:

   2.1. rename the project folder (e.g. `mv myproject newproject`)

   2.2. get into the new project folder (e.g. `cd newproject`) and edit the `.name` file with a text editor.

Open the new project now in IntelliJ (you may want to remove the `workspace.xml` if you don't want to keep the open file history - I kept it)  and enjoy your new project!

Comment: If you're using gradle, you may also want to be sure to check and change rootProject.name in settings.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

For copy with rename I had to do one more step to get it to stop referencing the old module name. That was to right click on the module in the project pane and do Refactor > Rename ( or do Shift + F6 ) to rename the module.

This was for IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3

Answer (score 2):

I had a gradle project and the provided answers did not work. The project did not have a structure in IntelliJ and I did not see the source files.

**The following worked:**

1. Export project (Export to zip file)
2. Move the zip file somewhere new
3. Unzip
4. With IntelliJ, import as a new project with "open".

Better Solution of course:

Have it in a git directory, make a "test-branch" and try whatever you want to try.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. It says Class XXX is not found in module YYY. Could  anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the accepted answer doesn't work anymore with current versions of Idea and the many derived IDEs (I tried this with PHPStorm). The problem: most of the config files are located in the `.idea` subdirectory of your project, but the file `.idea/workspace.xml` also contains the `ProjectId`, and that should of course be unique. So, if you copied the project directory manually, the easiest fix is to change the `ProjectId` - from what I have seen you can enter any alphanumeric string, e.g. `"ProjectId123"`.

As far as I can see the main settings that are stored under the `ProjectId` are the workspace settings, under `~/.config/JetBrains/[IDENameAndVersion]/workspace/[ProjectId].xml`. This file mostly contains the open editor tabs (with paths relative to the project directory) and the tool windows, so if you copy the project directory, you will always have the same editor tabs open in both projects (containing the "same" files, but from the respective project). If you want to avoid opening all files and setting up the tool windows, you can copy the old `[ProjectId].xml` file to e.g. `ProjectId123.xml` (using the `ProjectId` that you entered earlier).

Comment: yes,you are right, I found it , i clone a project , but they alway use same bookmarks , because bookmarks are stored in <ide-config-dir>/workspace/[ProjectId].xml , and 2 project both use the same  xml file

Answer (score 0):

After Copying your existing Project to a new folder don't forget to mark your **src** directory as **Source** directory. You can do this under **Project Structure |  Modules**.