# Is there a way to clone an IntelliJ IDEA gradle project?

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to move my IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3) Android project to another computer just copying the files and it does not work. I am aware of [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000003910-Copying-a-Project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034874/how-can-i-clone-a-whole-project-in-intellij-idea), but in the case of Android project it does not work. All the xml files inside .idea store paths relative to the home ($USER_HOME$) instead of project home ($PROJECT_DIR$). Oddly, Maven projects seem to generate paths relative to the project home and those ones can be copied. But not with gradle projects.

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

**EDIT**: Bear in mind that I want to copy ALL project settings included running configurations. I want that someone opens the project and find exactly what I have. I know I can reimport the project, but then I'll loose some configuration.

Comment: Have you tried re-importing the (IntelliJ) project from the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @BastienJansen I'll edit the question since it is not clear. I want to copy all the project settings, running configuration included.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the files and folders that need to be excluded from the copy (assuming that your project has a module called `app`), preferably if you copy the entire project folder to some where else on the same computer and then deleting the unneeded one by one:

- folders `.idea`, `.gradle` or any folder who's name starts with a `.`. They are usually found within the root folder of the project and within the module root folder.
- `build` folder found in the project root folder and in module root folder.
- any file who's extension is `.iml`, found in the project root folder and in module root folder.
- `local.properties` found in project root folder.

The rest of the files and folders need to be kept. With the above excluded, the project can be re-imported in Android Studio properly with the correct configurations relative to your second PC.

On a side note, these are the typical exclusions added in `.gitignore` of an Android Project Git Repo.

Comment: The thing is that I would like to copy also the settings of the project, running configurations included. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Then I believe the file that needs to be kept is the `.idea/workspace.xml`. To be honest haven't tried it before but I looked into the file and it seems it contains all the run/debug configs in it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. It is related to how gradle resolve symlinks. [This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134587) is the issue. Summarizing, if you open your project with a path that contains a symlink, absolute paths will be created in the configuration files and your project won't be portable.

I have reopened the project again using an absolute path and then all the configuration files use PROJECT_DIR instead of USER_HOME